# understanding Javascript grammar: user = user | | this.getUser()

Tags: javascript

For context you can find the full class definition @ https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/master/this%20%26%20object%20prototypes/ch6.md

I am trying to understand this particular expression found under "Simpler Design"

`LoginController.prototype.validateEntry = function(user,pw) {
    user = user || this.getUser(); //this is the statement I can't follow
    pw = pw || this.getPassword();`

If `user = undefined` or `user = ""`, then `user = user //false`. For any string values `user = user //true`. But in these cases `user = user;` evaluates to the same value as simply `user;`

1) is there any added functionality by writing `user = user;` instead of just `user`;?

2) why is the JavaScript engine able to evaluate a LHS assignment as a boolean value?

Comment: You have your operator precedence wrong. It makes much more sense when you put the operations in the right order.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In javascript, when you do `||` it's not necessarily returning a boolean, it will return the first non-falsy value.

It's basically saying set `user` to either the current value of `user`, or, if that is null, false, or undefined, set it to whatever `this.getUser()` returns.